# Docker/Kubernetes - failed to pull image from local repository

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes

I'm very new to docker/kubernetes. I built a docker image on my AWS EC2 instance that I can run using

```
sudo docker run imagename
```

This runs successfully. I can also see the image exists in the local docker repository when I run

```
sudo docker image ls
```

(note: I must use sudo or these commands give permission errors)

Now I'm trying to have kubernetes kick off a job which creates a container with that image, but when I do I get the following error:

```
Failed to pull image "imagename": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for imagename, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Here is the Python/flask code I'm using to try to create the job with the kubernetes API. The job successfully creates on the server, but when I check the kubernetes log that's where I see the error.

```
config.load_kube_config()
api_client = client.BatchV1Api()

container = client.V1Container(
    name="premium",
    image="imagename",
    resources=client.V1ResourceRequirements(requests={'cpu':'.9'}, limits={'cpu':'2'}),
    env=[client.V1EnvVar(name='dataset', value=ds )]
    )

# Create and configurate a spec section
template = client.V1PodTemplateSpec(
    metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(labels={"app": "premium"}),
    spec=client.V1PodSpec(restart_policy="Never", containers=[container]))

# Create the specification of deployment
spec = client.V1JobSpec(
    template=template,
    backoff_limit=4)

# Instantiate the job object
job = client.V1Job(
    api_version="batch/v1",
    kind="Job",
    metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(generate_name = 'premium-job-'),
    spec=spec)

api_response = api_client.create_namespaced_job("default", job, pretty=True)
```

Comment: does your cluster have access to pull down this image from the repository where you pushed it to?

Comment: They are on the same server so I would assume so but I don't know how to check. I didn't push the repository anywhere, it's just on the EC2 instance as evident by running `sudo docker images ls`. That's where I'm trying to pull it from.

Comment: `docker image ls` shows what is on your _local_ machine. kubernetes pulls from an image repository

Comment: So if the image exists on the EC2 instance (locally), and my kubernetes is running on the same instance, how do I bridge that gap? Must I push it to an external repository just to pull it?

Comment: AWS has a registry where you can push to. in general in order for it to spin up a pod it has to pull from a registry.

Comment: Your local machine (server) isn't really a repository (unless you've specifically set it up there as a service) -- so, as suggested, you should [set up a repository on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-create.html) or elsewhere (possibly start with a public image for testing) and push to that. Is the k8s master on the same server? Are you using minikube or similar?

Comment: Note if you add the `docker` group to the user you are logged in as, it should fix the `sudo` issue when running docker commands.

Comment: Note that if you can run any `docker` command at all, you can read and write arbitrary files on the host as root; requiring `sudo` permissions is a reasonable precaution.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Can you try to set `imagePullPolicy` to `Never` so that the image is pulled from your local docker registry? Is it `minikube` or `kubeadm` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Docker images are available on all nodes of the Kubernetes cluster. the image should be available on all nodes / you need to mention `nodeSelector` property. to run pod on exact same node where your image is present.

Now coming to your error. I saw similar problem with local images. `imagePullPolicy` property of the pod is making a problem here. its default value is `always` meaning it k8s (more specifically kubelet)  try to pull the image to pull image it tries to do docker login (maybe just to compare remote and local images) and gets failed.

How to solve the problem? Set `imagePullPolicy` to `ifNotPresent` or `never` so that it won't try to pull the image (and not tries to do docker login).

[read more here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)

I am giving a pointer for a standalone pod. It should be the same for a job. after all, it runs in pod only.